# Could anyone help me to solve this problem

Tags: logarithms

Honestly I've never been good with logarithms, they mess my head.

In the equation;
$$\log_{10}(ax)\log_{10}(bx)+1=0$$

with $a>0$, $b>0$ and $x>0$

This equation only has solutions when the ratio $b/a$ is in the interval $(0,m]$ or the interval $[M,\infty)$.  I need to find these intervals (i.e the $m$ and the $M$).

I don't know how to answer this, I tried to expand the expression and change 1 to the right adding the base then to $-1$ and try to solve from there but it was useless the far I've been is ;

$$\log_{10}(a)\log_{10}(b)+\log_{10}(a)\log_{10}(x)+\log_{10}(b)\log_{10}(x)+\log_{10}(x)^2+1=0$$

Comment: You should type math with dollar signs, like this:```$a<b$``` for $a<b$, and use the underscore for subscripts, like ```$\log_{10}(ax)$``` for $\log_{10}(ax)$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make the changes.

Comment: What is the task here? Does the cryptic notation `>=a/b>` mean that you want to find the ratio $\frac ab$ as a function of $x$? That sounds somewhat unlikely -- if you have $a,b,x$ that satisfy your equation, then interchanging $a$ and $b$ will _also_ satisfy your equation but it will give a different $\frac ab$.

Comment: What does $>=a/b>$ mean?

Comment: Trying to find the intervals

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Using
$$A=\log_{10}(a)\qquad B=\log_{10}(b) \qquad X=\log_{10}(x)$$ you last equation write
$$ X^2+(A +B) X+(A B +1)=0$$ If it has a root, then ....

Comment: typo . . . should be $B = \log_{10}(b)$  (I would have just fixed it, but "edits" have to be at least 6 characters.)

Comment: @SelrachDunbar. Thanks for pointing the typo (copy/paste problem). Cheers :-)